# Lower bound of a positive self-adjoint operator

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A$ be a positive self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space. Is there a way to show that $$\inf_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|=\inf_{\|x\|=1}|\langle x,Ax\rangle|$$
without using the spectral theorem and in a way similar to the proof of 
$\displaystyle \|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|\langle x,Ax\rangle|$ ?
A book reference will also be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My proof below is incomplete: for operators, positivity does not mean invertibility.  I believe, however, that that case in which the infimum is zero can be handled separately.

---

I'm not sure how you proved the statement about the sup without the spectral theorem, but that'll be enough for the opposite statement.

Note that since $A$ is positive, it is invertible, and $A^{-1}$ is positive.  We have
$$
\sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|A^{-1}x\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1}|\langle x,A^{-1}x\rangle|
$$
from there, we note that
$$
\inf_{\|x\| = 1} \|Ax\| = \left[\sup_{\|x\| = 1} \frac{1}{\|Ax\|}\right]^{-1} =
\left[\sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{x^*x}{x^*AAx}\right]^{-1/2} =(\text{set }y = Ax)\\
\left[\sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{y^*A^{-1}A^{-1}y}{y^*y}\right]^{-1/2} = \left[\sup_{\|y\|=1}\|A^{-1}y\|\right]^{-1}
$$
Similarly, show that
$$
\inf_{\|x\| = 1}|\langle x,A x\rangle| = \left[\sup_{\|y\| = 1}|\langle y,A^{-1}y \rangle| \right]^{-1}
$$
the statement follows.

Comment: Thanks, but I may need more of your help as I'm getting stuck on your last statement (by the way, we don't need to use |.| since everything is positive).

Comment: I'll put something here if I think of it

Comment: If $A$ has nontrivial kernel, then the equality holds trivially since both sides are zero. However if it's not invertible because it isn't surjective, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think that if subjectivity fails, the infimum is zero. Haven't given it much thought though

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think it's pretty easy to see if the range isn't dense but the dense range case isn't obvious to me. It could be the case that you can't have a positive operator with dense (non-full) range; I've never thought about it one way or the other.

Comment: @CameronWilliams if it's bounded and positive then the image is closed. Not sure what to say about unbounded maps

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh duh of course.